# How to pass local parameters into event handler outside of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Apologies for a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer that helps me yet.

If an event handler is outside the function/scope in which the event takes place, what is the proper way to write that? The way I have it right now seems to ignore the "inner" event and calls the handler when the "outer" event is called.

Instead of the text being appended every time "Download" is clicked, it is only added when "Generate Report" is clicked. It's like it is ignoring the `$("#download").on('click')` part altogether.

```js
$('#gen-report').on('click', function() {
  $('div').fadeIn();
  var example = "var from inside gen-report function"
  $('#divbutton').on('click', handler(example));

});

function handler(e) {
  $('div').append('<br>report downloaded with ');
  $('div').append(e);
}

$('#close').on('click', function() {
  $('div').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
[set options for report]
<button id="gen-report">
Generate Report
</button>
<div style="display:none; background:pink;">
  ~generated report~
  <button id="divbutton">
Download
</button>
</div>
```

And is there a better/more streamlined way to write this type of event handling?

Comment: You really want to posy a complete example here if you want people to help!

Comment: Side note, you should really avoid creating event bindings inside other event bindings.  This is a sure fire way to create duplicate bindings and run into unexpected behavior because you are repeating logic that you did not intend to do.

Comment: Every time you click `#gen-report` you are adding another click event to `$('#divbutton')` - I don't see any code that removes the element or unbind the handler. Eventually you will end up with several duplicate executions when you click `$('#divbutton')`

Comment: I see. It was originally outside, but I was unsure how to pass a variable that was created inside the gen-report click function, hence question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing `handler(example)` on click of `gen-report`, instead of hooking up the event.

One thing you can do, instead of using the `example` variable, attach the contents to the data of the internal button, or in a global variable or hidden DOM element. For example:

```
$('#gen-report').on('click', function() {
  $('div').fadeIn();
  var example = "var from inside gen-report function";
  $("#divbutton").data("example", example);
});

$('#divbutton').on('click', function() {
    var example = jQuery(this).data("example");
    // Go
});
```

If you hook up the event for `divbutton` inside the click handler for `gen-report`, you'll append to its click handler - so if you click `gen-report` twice, you'll end up with duplicate handlers for `divbutton`, and they'll both run. That's why I'm moving its handler outside.

**EDIT**

If you go with a global variable instead: when I say "global" variable, I don't actually mean totally global, just in scope of the whole deal - try to avoid truly global variables whenever possible:

```
// Don't do:
var example;
$('#gen-report').on('click', function() {/**/});
$('#divbutton').on('click', function() {/**/});

// Do:
(function() {
    var example;
    $('#gen-report').on('click', function() {/**/});
    $('#divbutton').on('click', function() {/**/});
})();
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that.. works great, thanks! And yes, I try to avoid globals but thats a helpful tip.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add an event handler inside another event handler, unless you remove the old handler first. Every time you click on `Generate Report` it will add another handler to `Download`, then when you click on `Download` it will run it multiple times.

You should make `example` a global variable, and move the `Download` click handler outside. Then you just need to fix that to call the `handler()` function when you click, not immedediately.

```js
var example;
$('#gen-report').on('click', function() {
  $('div').fadeIn();
  example = "var from inside gen-report function"
});

$('#divbutton').on('click', function() {
  if (example) {
    handler(example);
  } else {
    alert("Click on Generate Report first");
  }
});

function handler(e) {
  $('div').append('<br>report downloaded with ');
  $('div').append(e);
}

$('#close').on('click', function() {
  $('div').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
[set options for report]
<button id="gen-report">
Generate Report
</button>
<div style="display:none; background:pink;">
  ~generated report~
  <button id="divbutton">
Download
</button>
</div>
```